# Getting Distribution Groups / Owners w/ PowerShell, but removing entries that have a null or empty owner

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have the lovely job of getting a list of Distribution Groups and their owners from Exchange Online. So far this is working great, but I need to fine tune my output to exclude groups that don't have any owners; and groups that have multiple owners (by returning only the first).

So far this has been fairly difficult as this is sort of my first foray into PShell.
Here's my code:

```
$job = Get-DistributionGroup | select Name,PrimarySmtpAddress, @{n= "ManagedBy"; e={$_.ManagedBy | Select-Object -First 1 | Where-Object {$_.ManagedBy.Count -eq 0} |foreach {(Get-Mailbox $_).PrimarySMTPAddress}}}


Write-Output $job | ConvertTo-Json
```

Here's an example of my output: [image: Screenshot of Output]

I basically only want a single string address to be returned. So a single owner of a distro group, no nulls, and only the first address in the collections. (Right now they are blank, I'm probably nuking them with my code- but usually they return 4 or so email addresses but I just want the first person)

Thanks!

Comment: So what you have right seems Okay, you just need to exclude objects where `ManagedBy` is null, so `Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object ManagedBy | Select-Object ....` If I understood correctly. Then this condition could be removed `| Where-Object {$_.ManagedBy.Count -eq 0}`

Comment: Yeah I pulled that out, but I don't think the Select-Object is working. My collection just ends up blank like you see in that Screenshot of Output up there.

Comment: By collection you mean the `ManagedBy` property right? If so, try with `{ ($_.ManagedBy | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Mailbox).PrimarySMTPAddress }`

Comment: I could kiss you, thanks man! That did the trick. Looks like I just wasn't bracketing/parenthesizing properly.

Comment: yay glad it worked :) you can post it as an answer to your question so it might help others with a similar question / issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

By collection you mean the ManagedBy property right? If so, try with `{ ($_.ManagedBy | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Mailbox).PrimarySMTPAddress }` –
Santiago Squarzon
1 hour ago